# Missing Display Javascript Demo from Github Repository On JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, jsfiddle

I have a repository [on github](https://github.com/viyancs/JS-Fiddle-Experiment/tree/master/dropdown/demo/), and I want to display on JSFiddle. I tried this tutorial 
http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/github_read.html. But when I access this [url](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jQuery/1.8.2/viyancs/JS-Fiddle-Experiment/tree/master/Drop-Down-Jquery-Custom), I don't see anything, just a jsfiddle template.

How can I show my javascript Demo in JSFiddle using a github repository?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: could it be because of line 16 in dropdown.js?

Comment: i'm fixing by remove )) but still not show...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found to fixing that issue,

the name file js,css,html,details is recommended 'demo'(without quote)

check this [url](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.8.2/viyancs/JS-Fiddle-Experiment/tree/master/dropdown/demo/)